# Simulating different locations for automatic testing

Tags: automated-tests

For a hobby project of mine, I'm building automatic test software for a complex website.

What the automatic test software does until now is:

- Open the website
- Do stuff on website
- Write results to a file
- Close website

Pretty straight forward and works like a charm.

The website is made to have a certain behaviour among other things based on the location you're accessing it from.

To test different kind of locations, I use ExpressVPN. Works like a charm again....

But while the "Doing stuff on the website"-part takes away a lot of effort from my side, I'd wish I could  automate the changing of the VPN location (or accomplish the same thing in a completely different way). Has anybody any ideas?

Comment: How does the website determine the user's location? For testing you could add something like an URL parameter `location` where you pass in a fake location, and based on that the site changes its behaviour.

Comment: That would be the easy way, but I can't change anything about the website and it doesn't work with an URL parameter

Comment: Since I can simulate a different location using VPN, I assume/guess it uses the IP adress from the device it's accessed from

Comment: Quick google search shows that it is possible to do that in code, eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899349/connecting-to-a-vpn-without-installation-of-client-software
So it depends on what programming language you're using.

Comment: @ChristianBaumann For now i've written it in VBA, but if solving this problem requires me to rewrite the rest of the code in another language, that's no problem

Comment: Found a solution, will post it as answer

Answer (score 1):

After some more googling, chasing down rabbit holes, sleepless nights and lots of trial and error, I found the solution. It takes some (a lot of) preparation, but if you use it a lot, like I'm planning to do, it's worth the effort....

**Preparation**

- Download and install Open VPN GUI
- Download config files for Open VPN from ExpressVPN
- Edit config files according to info from ExpressVPN (used a script for that, but if you are only doing a few, might do that by hand)
- Use OpenVPN to connect to all the servers (to enter credentials), this only has to be done once (if you don't forget to check the box "Remember password")

**Actual code**
It's a pretty simple code (I know that this snippet is quick and dirty, have to add error handling and stuff, but I was happy I got it working)

```html
Dim DirectoryListArray() As String
Dim myDir as String
Dim myFile as String
Dim Counter as Integer
Dim strCommand as String
Dim i as Integer

myDir = "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin\"
ReDim DirectoryListArray(1000)

MyFile = Dir$("C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config\*.*")
Do While myFile <> ""
    DirectoryListArray(Counter) = myFile
    myFile = Dir$
    Counter = Counter + 1
Loop

ReDim Preserve DirectoryListArray(Counter - 1)

For i = 1 To UBound(DirectoryListArray)
    strCommand = "openvpn-gui.exe --command disconnect_all"
    Call Shell("cmd.exe /c cd /d " & myDir & " & " & strCommand, 1)
    strCommand = "openvpn-gui.exe --command connect " & DirectoryListArray(i)
    Call Shell("cmd.exe /c cd /d " & myDir & " & " & strCommand, 1)

    'Do Stuff on website

Next i
```